# Xcode Refactor "Convert to Switch"

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode Refactor has a function called "Convert to Switch". I am looking for an example of code which can be used by the function and be converted to switch flow statement.

Comment: I've updated an answer, hope it'll be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

As you've pointed out, `Convert to Switch` != `Convert To Switch Statement`. In order to understand why, we need to know how Xcode refactoring feature works under the hood.

What I've found:

Here's a great article on the topic:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/uncovering-xcode-indexing-8b3f3ff82551

It points us to a `swift` open-source repo: https://github.com/apple/swift

Xcode refactoring is done with a `SourceKit` framework, which is inside a swift repo.

Here's a SourceKit protocol for communication with Xcode: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/tools/SourceKit/docs/Protocol.md

Internally, when we choose "Refactor", Xcode *somehow* (via XPC) sends *something* like `source.request.workspace.refactoring` message to a SourceKit. And there's an "indexed file" somewhere, so `SourceKit` can instantly (not in 5 minutes :)) propose you the options which are adequate/possible for a current snippet of code.

I've loaded `swift` repo from github (it's about 30MB), navigated into `SourceKit` code and tried to find stuff related to `source.request.workspace.refactoring`.

Somewhere in the code is a reference to `swift/IDE/RefactoringKinds.def`. I'll copy-paste the contents of this file:

```
#ifndef REFACTORING
#define REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID)
#endif

#ifndef SEMANTIC_REFACTORING
#define SEMANTIC_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID) REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID)
#endif

#ifndef RANGE_REFACTORING
#define RANGE_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID) SEMANTIC_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID)
#endif

#ifndef INTERNAL_RANGE_REFACTORING
#define INTERNAL_RANGE_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID) RANGE_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID)
#endif

#ifndef CURSOR_REFACTORING
#define CURSOR_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID) SEMANTIC_REFACTORING(KIND, NAME, ID)
#endif

/// Rename and categorise the symbol occurrences at provided locations
/// (syntactically).
REFACTORING(GlobalRename, "Global Rename", rename.global)

/// Categorize source ranges for symbol occurrences at provided locations
/// (syntactically).
REFACTORING(FindGlobalRenameRanges, "Find Global Rename Ranges", rename.global.find-ranges)

/// Find and categorize all occurences of the file-local symbol at a given
/// location.
REFACTORING(FindLocalRenameRanges, "Find Local Rename Ranges", rename.local.find-ranges)

/// Find and rename all occurences of the file-local symbol at a given
/// location.
CURSOR_REFACTORING(LocalRename, "Local Rename", rename.local)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(FillProtocolStub, "Add Missing Protocol Requirements", fillstub)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(ExpandDefault, "Expand Default", expand.default)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(ExpandSwitchCases, "Expand Switch Cases", expand.switch.cases)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(LocalizeString, "Localize String", localize.string)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(SimplifyNumberLiteral, "Simplify Long Number Literal", simplify.long.number.literal)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(CollapseNestedIfStmt, "Collapse Nested If Statements", collapse.nested.ifstmt)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(ConvertToDoCatch, "Convert To Do/Catch", convert.do.catch)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(TrailingClosure, "Convert To Trailing Closure", trailingclosure)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(MemberwiseInitLocalRefactoring, "Generate Memberwise Initializer", memberwise.init.local.refactoring)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(AddEquatableConformance, "Add Equatable Conformance", add.equatable.conformance)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(ConvertCallToAsyncAlternative, "Convert Call to Async Alternative", convert.call-to-async)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(ConvertToAsync, "Convert Function to Async", convert.func-to-async)

CURSOR_REFACTORING(AddAsyncAlternative, "Add Async Alternative", add.async-alternative)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ExtractExpr, "Extract Expression", extract.expr)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ExtractFunction, "Extract Method", extract.function)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ExtractRepeatedExpr, "Extract Repeated Expression", extract.expr.repeated)

RANGE_REFACTORING(MoveMembersToExtension, "Move To Extension", move.members.to.extension)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ConvertStringsConcatenationToInterpolation, "Convert to String Interpolation", convert.string-concatenation.interpolation)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ExpandTernaryExpr, "Expand Ternary Expression", expand.ternary.expr)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ConvertToTernaryExpr, "Convert To Ternary Expression", convert.ternary.expr)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ConvertIfLetExprToGuardExpr, "Convert To Guard Expression", convert.iflet.to.guard.expr)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ConvertGuardExprToIfLetExpr, "Convert To IfLet Expression", convert.to.iflet.expr)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ConvertToComputedProperty, "Convert To Computed Property", convert.to.computed.property)

RANGE_REFACTORING(ConvertToSwitchStmt, "Convert To Switch Statement", convert.switch.stmt)

// These internal refactorings are designed to be helpful for working on
// the compiler/standard library, etc., but are likely to be just confusing and
// noise for general development.

INTERNAL_RANGE_REFACTORING(ReplaceBodiesWithFatalError, "Replace Function Bodies With 'fatalError()'", replace.bodies.with.fatalError)

#undef CURSOR_REFACTORING
#undef INTERNAL_RANGE_REFACTORING
#undef RANGE_REFACTORING
#undef SEMANTIC_REFACTORING
#undef REFACTORING
```

As you see, there's `Convert To Switch Statement` here, and `Expand Switch Cases`, but not `Convert To Switch`.

So my guess is that what Xcode shows us in UI, is either a bug (they forgot to delete an outdated stuff), or a part of some implementation which is not in a current version of a Swift repo.

Anyway, you may dig even deeper - I've just tried to investigate it in a short period of time. :)
If you really need this done, then except of exploring `SourceKit` protocols, I guess you can open an issue on Github - maybe those who know it will explain a real reason.

#### Initial answer

Let's consider such an example:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case option1, option2, option3
}

func convertToSwitchExampleFunc(_ option: SomeEnum) {
    if option == .option1 {
        print("1")
    }
    if option == .option2 {
        print("2")
    }
    if option == .option3 {
        print("3")
    }
}

func callingFunc() {
    convertToSwitchExampleFunc(.option2)
}
```

If you select all code inside the body of `convertToSwitchExampleFunc`, then choose `Refactor`, Xcode won't show you "Convert to Switch".

But if you change the code such that it's more similar to an ugly "switch" implementation (`if-else-if-else` chain):

```
func convertToSwitchExampleFunc(_ option: SomeEnum) {
    if option == .option1 {
        print("1")
    }
    else if option == .option2 {
        print("2")
    }
    else if option == .option3 {
        print("3")
    }
}
```

Then Xcode will show you "Convert to Switch menu", and an auto-refactored code will look like this:

```
func convertToSwitchExampleFunc(_ option: SomeEnum) {
    switch option {
    case .option1:
        print("1")
    case .option2:
        print("2")
    case .option3:
        print("3")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Just to give more context:
[image]

Comment: Thx, it works not only with enums but as well with strings. On your screenshot, on the list of refactor functions you can find "Convert to Switch" which is disabled and "Convert To Switch Statement". What is a difference between them?

Comment: Thank you for this exploratory investigation and those insightful comments.